# numpy masking does not work with bounded range on both sides

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose we have:

```
>>> x
array([-1. , -1.3,  0. ,  1.3,  0.2])
```

We can choose select elements with a range:

```
>>> x[x <= 1]
array([-1. , -1.3,  0. ,  0.2])
```

And we can bound it below too:

```
>>> x[-1 <= x]
array([-1. ,  0. ,  1.3,  0.2])
```

Is there some rationale for not being able to use the following:

```
>>> x[-1 <= x <= 1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I know that all it does is create a mask of `True` and `False`s upon doing these inequality operations, and so I can do the following:

```
>>> x[(-1 <= x) * (x <= 1)]
array([-1. ,  0. ,  0.2])
```

as a broadcasting operation on booleans. It's not too inconvenient, but why doesn't the previous range inequality work?

Answer (score 1):

Although regular Python types do support "chained comparison" like `1 < x < 5`, NumPy arrays do not.  Perhaps that's unfortunate, but you can work around it easily:

```
x[(-1 <= x) & (x <= 1)]
```

Comment: Better to use `np.logical_and`.

Comment: @Kasramvd: What's better about it?

Comment: `&` is generally a bit-wise `and` and the reason it works as expected here has nothing to do with the intention behind using it. So for refusing of such confusions it's better to use a `logical_and` function.

Comment: @Kasramvd: I think you'll agree they give the same result.  It also happens that `&` is a bit faster (15% faster on my system).  Plus, `&` is quite conventional, and can be seen in lots of NumPy code "in the wild" (whereas if we were writing C I would agree with you not to use `&`).

Comment: @kasravnd This usage is explicitly mentioned by the doc: "The ``&`` operator can be used as a shorthand for ``np.logical_and`` on boolean ndarrays.".